# Webdriver Ruby Bindings - Setting Capabilities

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am using Ruby bindings for Webdriver and need to set a particular capability when creating a webdriver instance for IE.  The capabilitiy is :ignore_zoom_setting.  However, the options I can pass through to the driver are limited to :timeout, :port, :http_client, :introduce_flakiness_by_ignoring_security_domains, and :native_events.

The only way I've found of passing a desired capabilities object is if I use remote webdriver. Can I somehow call Selenium::WebDriver.for :ie and pass in capabilities as well?

Mark

Answer (score 1):

Oh yes you can. here is the code snippet that should help you

oops gave code for java. I will let it be there but for ruby you do need to use remote

```rb
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.htmlunit(:javascript_enabled => true)
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :remote, :url => "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub", :desired_capabilities => caps
```

**For Java**

```java
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setJavascriptEnabled(false);
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(cap);
```

Comment: Thanks Prashant, however I want it to NOT be a remote webdriver instance.

Comment: @MarkMicallef yeah man I wrote the answer even before reading the full requirement. Sorry about that. A section on [http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#internet-explorer) does state that it is not implemented for anything else but remotedriver.