# how do I set elementScrollBehavior to 1 using the ruby bindings for Selenium:WebDriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, capybara

In the context of a capybara test, I'm trying to set elementScrollBehavior to 1 (instructing webdriver to scroll elements targeted for interaction to the bottom of the viewport).  I sort of expected this to work:

`Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox('elementScrollBehavior' => 1)
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, desired_capabilities: capabilities)
end`

but it does not.

Comment: A similar question here was asked 3 years ago with no answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036698/webdriver-ruby-bindings-setting-capabilities#.  It looks like I shouldn't be using remote capabilities but no alternative was offered

Comment: The way you are setting the elementScrollBehaviour does work. How are you verifying that the setting is not being set? There was a bug recently opened that the [elementScrollBehaviour is only being used when calling the `location_once_scrolled_into_view` method](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1200) (in Selenium).

Comment: @JustinKo thanks for the tip.  It doesn't seem to matter if I use selenium-webdriver 2.45.0 or 2.48.1.  I can watch firefox and it doesn't behavior differently when I change the value of 'elementScrollBehavior'.  As background, my problem is that I have a fixed header on the page and I thought this setting might allow my specs to pass because capybara things the elements under the header are invisible (as they well are).  Currently I'm just hiding the header when I run specific parts of my specs.

Comment: Any chance you can share a working page that shows the same problem?